# Delete a drop down item after selecting another drop down value (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete an item (ItemX) from a drop down menu  (Drop Down 2) when `ItemX` is selected in `Drop Down 1` using Jquery.

I am working in a way;

```
<?php
session_start ();

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<form action = 'testselectprocess.php' method='POST'>

<div>
<select id="cat"></select> <select id="items" disabled></select>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var c = '<option>Select</option>';
var cat1 = ["Honey", "Tree", "Chocolate"];
for (i=0; i < cat1.length; i++){
 c += '<option>' + cat1[i] + '</options>';
}
$('#cat')
 .html(c)
 .change(function(){
  var indx = this.selectedIndex - 1;
  if (indx < 0) {
   $('#items').empty().attr('disabled','disabled');
   return;
  }
  var item = '<option>Select an item</option>';
  for (i=0; i < cat1.length; i++){
    item += '<option>' + cat1[i] + '</options>';
  }
  $('#items').html(item).removeAttr('disabled');
 });

});

</script>


</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

There are two drop downs in the above code. In which both have three values `Honey`, `Tree`, `Chocolate`. I need that if a user select `Honey` from first drop down then `Honey` should be invisible or delete from second drop down.

Comment: little example with jquery, may be helpful
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6488/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do any check and not added the selected value you just copy all items from the first select to the second one.

So the solution is to validate and not copy the the selected item, like this:

```
<?php

session_start ();

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<form action = 'testselectprocess.php' method='POST'>

<div>
<select id="cat"></select> <select id="items" disabled></select>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var c = '<option>Select</option>';
var cat1 = ["Honey", "Tree", "Chocolate"];
for (i=0; i < cat1.length; i++){
 c += '<option>' + cat1[i] + '</options>';
}
$('#cat')
 .html(c)
 .change(function(){
  var indx = this.selectedIndex - 1;
  if (indx < 0) {
   $('#items').empty().attr('disabled','disabled');
   return;
  }
  var item = '<option>Select an item</option>';
  for (i=0; i < cat1.length; i++){
    item += indx !== i ? '<option>' + cat1[i] + '</options>' : '';
  }
  $('#items').html(item).removeAttr('disabled');
 });

});

</script>


</form>

 </body>
</html>
```